# onClick function is called on render -- how can I stop this from occurring?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

A React component should not call a function every time it's rendered. Why in my case is it getting called on render?

ex.)

```
const onClick = () => {
    console.log('hi');
}

<button onClick={onClick}>CLICK</button>
```

I wonder where the onClick function is called when there is a code like above.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when I started using React, and the solution is to add an arrow function before the onClick:

```
    const onClick = () => {
    console.log('hi');
}

    return(
    <button onClick={() => onClick()}>CLICK</button>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like HTML, React can perform actions based on user events. An HTML event can be something the browser does, or something a user does. For example, clicking on a button, hovering over an image with your mouse, etc.

The `onClick` is just one of many event handler and gets executed when user clicks on the associated element.

**The difference in syntax b/w HTML and JSX**: `onClick={shoot}` in react/JSX and `onClick="shoot()"` in HTML.

1. I'd recommend reading about [Javascript Events](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp).
2. It seems like you are interested in learning the internal working of react events so for that you can refer to [`SyntheticEvent`](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html) docs on react's website.